# How to express inheritance in (Neo4j) graph database?

Tags: database, graph, neo4j

If I have an object "player" which is a subcategory of "person", how do I express that in a graph?

Here's an example: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/adzDF.png]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use multiple labels:

```
create ... (:Player:Person {name:'a player'}) ...
```

In general you assign all the labels up the inheritance tree. This way doing a

```
match (:Person) return n
```

would return all the players as well.